# How would I chunk up a list to write to text file due to running out of memory issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, python-itertools

```
import itertools, hashlib, pandas as pd,time, re
chars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
rows = []
removechars1 = ["(",")","'",","," "]
removechars2 = [","," ","-"]
pattern1 = '[' +  ''.join(removechars1) +  ']'
pattern2 = '[' +  ''.join(removechars2) +  ']'
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 10):
        for A in numbers_list:
            pure = str(A) + ':' + str(combination) 
            B = re.sub(pattern1, '', pure)
            B1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in B.lower()]
            B2 = str(B1)
            B3 = re.sub(pattern2, '', B2)
            B4 = B3.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            C = hashlib.sha256(B.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            C1 = [ord(char) - 96 for char in C.lower()]
            C2 = str(C1)
            C3 = re.sub(pattern2, '', C2)
            C4 = C3.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            rows.append([str(A) , B3[:10], C3[:10]])
t0 = time.time()
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        for row in rows:
                f.write("%s\n" % str(row).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", ""))
f.close()        
tdelta = time.time() - t0
print(tdelta)
```

Good afternoon everyone,
Due to high number of combinations. the script causes my PC to slow down due to running out of memory. Is there a way to chunk up the date in the list being written to text file? I tried doing it line by line but the script run slow due to the amount of combinations. I am bit new to programing in python. I would be really appreciative the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't store your combinations in a list only to then iterate again through that list. Write each "row" directly as your iterate through the combinations generator:

```py
import itertools, hashlib, time, re
chars = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
# ...

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 10):
        for A in numbers_list:
            # ...
            row = [str(A), B3[:10], C3[:10]]
            f.write("%s\n" % str(row).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", ""))
```

Comment: Would writing each row in the text file cause so slowness? Would writing in chunks of rows in the text file at the same time be quicker? My apologies, I am a bit new with programing.

Comment: @JuanSotoValdez I'm not sure. Start with fewer combinations and experiment first